# React Native Splash Screen Navigation

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, react-native-splash-screen

The below code is my splash screen, this screen has to be displayed if the location is set otherwise I need to navigate to AuthSplashScreen.

```
componentDidUpdate () {
        debugger;
        if(this.props.location){
                    return this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset(
                    {
                        index: 0,
                        actions: [
                          NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home'})
                        ]
                    }));
                }else{
                     setTimeout(function(){
                        return this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset(
                        {
                            index: 0,
                            actions: [
                            NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'AuthSplashScreen'})
                            ]
                        }));
                     }, 1000)
                }
    }
```

Here, the issues are :
1) If I am using settimeout, the output cannot read the property 'naviagtion' of undefined.
2) If I remove the settimeout it will work perfectly and navigate **AuthSplashScreen**(when location is not set)/**Home**(when location is set) as required. But, it gives a **blinking** like a display at the time of changing the screen from SplashScreen to AuthSplashScreen.

**So how can I solve this blinking effect? Or do I need to change the logic of managing the screens?**

Comment: I think your setTimeout method is reason of blink effect

Comment: Blinking occurs after removing the settimeout

Comment: you are doing it in `componentDidUpdate()` method, so once the value of prop is updated then it will call

Comment: Why not use `componentDidMount()` instead of `componentDidUpdate()`? Then there is no reason for a timeout and the app will navigate after the component has finished fully loading

Comment: after getting the data from in this.props.location then only I can decide whether I need to navigate to AuthSplashScreen or not. And as soon as the props gets updated component lifecycle calls componentDidUpdate()

Answer (score 0):

Just need to keep a reference of the object of this.

```
componentDidUpdate () {
        debugger;
        if(this.props.location){
                    return this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset(
                    {
                        index: 0,
                        actions: [
                          NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home'})
                        ]
                    }));
                }else{
                     var thisObj = this;
                     setTimeout(function(){
                        return thisObj.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset(
                        {
                            index: 0,
                            actions: [
                            NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'AuthSplashScreen'})
                            ]
                        }));
                     }, 1000)
                }
    }
```